# Use of angular proxy in production

Tags: angular

I read that angular proxies are specific to development and are not intended for production use.

Can someone please explain me why ?

Comment: angular proxy (which is webpack proxy under the hood) is just the simple proxy with almost no security logic involved as well as it is probably far less performant as the usual proxy. also if you are using proxy you are most likely using development server, which does not make sense for production as well

Comment: @Andrei make it an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

angular proxy (which is webpack proxy under the hood) is just the simple proxy with almost no security logic involved as well as it is probably far less performant as the usual proxy. Also if you are using proxy you are most likely using development server, which does not make sense for production as well